# How to get a normalized staked bar chart using Incanter?

Tags: clojure, jfreechart, incanter

Following this example,

```
(use '(incanter core stats charts datasets))

(with-data  (get-dataset :airline-passengers)
  (view (stacked-bar-chart :month :passengers :group-by :year :legend true)))
```

How can I make each global bar equal to 100%, allowing full relative comparisons between stacked elements?

Now I get something like this :
[image: http://phloxblog.in/angulard3/images/Nor-Stackbar.jpg]

How can I achieve this instead?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
(use '(incanter core stats charts datasets))

(import
   '[org.jfree.chart ChartFactory ChartUtilities JFreeChart StandardChartTheme]
   '[org.jfree.chart.plot CategoryPlot]
   '[org.jfree.chart.renderer.category CategoryItemRenderer StackedBarRenderer])

(with-data  (get-dataset :airline-passengers)
  (view 
   (let [chart (stacked-bar-chart :month :passengers :group-by :year :legend true)
         plot (-> chart .getCategoryPlot)
         renderer (-> plot .getRenderer)
         _ (.setRenderAsPercentages renderer true)] 
     chart)))
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

If you want to get axis in percent, you can do

```
(use '(incanter core stats charts datasets))

(import
   '[org.jfree.chart ChartFactory ChartUtilities JFreeChart StandardChartTheme]
   '[org.jfree.chart.axis NumberAxis]
   '[org.jfree.chart.labels StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator ItemLabelPosition ItemLabelAnchor]
   '[org.jfree.chart.plot CategoryPlot]
   '[org.jfree.chart.renderer.category StackedBarRenderer]
   '[java.text DecimalFormat])

(with-data (get-dataset :airline-passengers)
  (view 
   (let [chart (stacked-bar-chart :month :passengers :group-by :year :legend true)
         plot (-> chart .getCategoryPlot)
         range-axis (-> plot .getRangeAxis)
         percent-format (DecimalFormat. "#%") ;;"#.0%"
         _ (.setNumberFormatOverride range-axis percent-format)
         renderer (-> plot .getRenderer) 
         _ (.setRenderAsPercentages renderer true)] 
     chart)))
```